# Drill down navigation in listview

Tags: android

I'm trying to do drilldown navigation in listview below are the methods which i'm following.

1. Use single activity and create multiple instances on click of listItems.
2. Using single listview and populate the listview based on onclick item.

The problem with this approach is when I click back button the app closes. How to get back to the parent path? Suppose if there are three levels a > b > c how to traverse back?. Which is the better approach?

Comment: If you get "app stopped unexpectedly", there should be the error stack trace in the log cat.  Please add it to your post.

Comment: no there is no error or expection currently i'm trying second method the problem is how to traverse back???